# php still waits for result when redirecting standard output and error during exec

Tags: php, shell

I’m running into an while trying to fire a php command without waiting for the results. The command I’m firing looks like this:

```
exec("cd /var/www/domains/path/to/tool/folder && /usr/bin/node _start.js >/dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

When I fire the cli command directly in the terminal it fires and "finishes" immediately as I would expect.

When I fire the full php line above, php still waits for a result.

When I was reading through php's docs on exec I'm seeing people explaining how [it's possible to fire the shell command without waiting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329), but even trying those versions of standard ouput/error redirection are not working.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: FYI you don't need both `>/dev/null` and  `1>/dev/null` they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's necessary, but when you combine commands with `&&`, you need to group them so the redirection applies to both commands.

```
exec("{ cd /var/www/domains/path/to/tool/folder && /usr/bin/node _start.js ; } >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I came to the same conclusion, though I did it via `exec("( cd /var/www/domains/path/to/tool/folder && /usr/bin/node _start.js ; ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &");`. Is there a functional difference between the brackets and the parens?

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Parenthese run the commands in a subshell, rather than just grouping them.